# geofirestore querydocumentsnapshot

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, geofirestore

Using geofirestore, I can query from collection `users/{userId}/pros` in cloud functions and get resulting documents(doc). Now I want to add a new collection `users/{userId}/pros/{proId}/notifs` right under each of the document `users/{userId}/pros/{proId}` that came from the query. So, I wrote like this;

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document("users/{user}/consumers/{consumer}")
.onCreate(async snapshot => {
try {

 query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
 querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    
 await doc.ref.collection('notifs').add({ . . .}); 

 }).catch ((error) =>
            console.log(error));
```

However I keep getting errors `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`. What seems to be wrong? Geofiretore queryDocumentSnapshot doesn't seem to have collection() property. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Presented part of the code does not seems to be a problem. It seems that somehow  `doc` has no `ref` property, but from presented part it's not possible to determine why.... is it possible to add more code?

Comment: Thanks for reply vitooh. I posted my whole code. I think it has something to do with geofirestore that I am using for my query. Please have a look and give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `docs` property missing before `forEach` loop. According to the `QuerySnapshot` [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) the property is:

> An array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot

So the if you want to loop over the docs it should be:

```
...
query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
 querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
...
```

According to my tests this will work at least directly in node (which is used in cloud function as well)